# Using a user entered string as an instance name in Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-debug

I am developing an android app in Java, where I have this contacts class defined.

What I want is that user enters a person name in an `EditText` and clicks a button and it becomes a instance name of a new instance of contact class.

For eg if user enters harry in `EditText` then something like this :

```
ButtonClick {
Contact harry = new Contact();
}
```

Another button click with entered name as Duke then

```
ButtonClick{
Contact Duke = new Contact();
}
```

I am new in this domain.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to achieve this.
Why do you even want to replace a fixed instance name with a user input string?
the user never gonna see the variable names
if you want to use the input string as key, however, you could use a map instead

Comment: Dynamically naming variables is one of those things that beginner programmers always seem to feel like they need, and they really don't. What are you going to do if a user enters "vibhum" as a username? Now you have a `Contact vibhum` object, but you have no code that knows how to deal with that object because you did not have that information at compile time.

Comment: @vibhummohan, welcome! What's the underlying problem you're trying to solve? Java variables cannot be renamed at runtime, nor would it help anything, e.g. the rest of the program wouldn't have such a variable. Do you want to be able to retrieve a Contact by name? In that case you could put the instances into a HashMap or a sqlite database.

Comment: Please consult: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) and its answer! Also seems like you have not yet completed the [tour]  :-/

Comment: Maybe a [Map](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map) is appropriate? The "key" would be the user-entered string and the "value" would be an instance of `Contact`.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I am trying to make a contact app in whichi want that when user enter a contact name and phone number then a new object of a contact class gets created with a same name that user entered that's why because every contact has to be an instance of contact class. For eg if i want to make any contact as a programmer i will write Contact vibhum = new Contact(name, ph num) and will call saveContact(vibhum) to save it in a sqlite DB then if i want to make a new contact I'll do Contact Robby = new Contact(name, phnum) So i just want that every time user presses button they can do same

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen is there any other way to achieve this, If you want i can share my whole code, Thank you so much for looking in this

Comment: @Jerry101 I am trying to make a contact app in which i want that when user enter a contact name and phone number then a new object of a contact class gets created with a same name that user entered that's why because every contact has to be an instance of contact class. For eg if i want to make any contact as a programmer i will write Contact vibhum = new Contact(name, ph num) and will call saveContact(vibhum) to save it in a sqlite DB then if i want to make a new contact I'll do Contact Robby = new Contact(name, phnum) So i just want that every time user presses button they can do same

Comment: @Jerry101 I see people here trying to make fun of me for that i am sad, but i thank you for actually trying to help me as this is something very imp to me that's why i am finding help here

Comment: Who's making fun of you? Look at it this way: what does it matter whether that variable is called `vibhum`, `user`, `user1`, or something else entirely? Or to clarify my previous comment: let's say I enter user name 'robby'. What are you going to do? Stop your application, change your code to create a `User robby`, recompile, and ask me to try again because you didn't have the right code to save a user with my particular user name?

Answer (score 0):

Understanding *names* in programming is a deep topic. The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/jls18.pdf) has a 60-page chapter on [Names](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-6.html) and even that doesn't get to your more fundamental question.

There's a **conceptual leap** for new programmers to get from how we might think about variables in algebra class to how we need to think about variables when programming a computer.

Writing code like this will not pan out:

```java
Contact vibhum = new Contact(email, phone);
database.save(vibhum);
println("New contact " + vibhum + " successfully created.");
```

The variable name `vibhum` is how this code refers to an instance of the `Contact` class. Changing it requires editing the code and recompiling the code. The variable name has no influence outside this piece of source code: the `Contact` object does not know its own name, it can't print its name, and saving it to a database can't store or retrieve it by name. The variable name is not even available to the running program (although it might be available to debugging tools).

Instead we need to write code like this:

```java
Contact c = new Contact("Vibhum", email, phone);
database.save(c);
println("New contact " + c + " successfully created.");
```

Now the `Contact` instance can remember, print, and save its user-visible name.

When a program deals with multiple Contacts, it should have variable names that relate to how it handles those Contacts, not with the Contact names. Examples:

```java
Contact sender = database.get("myself");

Contact c = database.getContact(name);
c.phone = newPhone;
c.friends.add(sender);
database.save(c);

for (Contact contact: emailList) { ... }
```

A program might operate on all the Contacts in a list (like `emailList`, above), or fetch a Contact by name or role from a database or from a list or other collection. In any case *the variable name is only how the source code distinguishes that variable from all the other objects it deals with.* The variable name has nothing to do with the external name of the Contact.

Consider programming a robot to swap two bolts in a parts tray: pick up the bolt from bin #5 to its right hand; pick up the bolt from bin #15 to its left hand; and put them down into the opposite bins. To the robot program, the variable names are "right" and "left". To the external world, the parts tray has bin numbers and the individual bolts might be distinguished by their lengths.

Comment: thank you so much, really appreciate your time and efforts thanks a ton!